# Packages in between ROS versions

Tags: ros, stack, ros-fuerte, release, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running fuerte on 12.04 and I realize it takes a lot of work trying to keep stacks up to date in the latest ROS releases. However, when a stack, in this case the p2os stack, appears to be supported in the previous ROS release (electric) and not yet in the current (fuerte), what do you do?

Should you wait until you can properly install it?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-p2os
```

Or is it alright/recommended to try and run something (stable) in a previous release in the current release -- by grabbing the old source from the repository by hand?

Or is there an alternative option? Or am I looking for a stack that has changed names in the current release?

Thanks! I really appreciate any insight.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42120/packages-in-between-ros-versions/) by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 549 on 2012-08-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2012-08-23**:
Great! Thanks for the response.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-07-09**:
Did  the p2os work in fuerte? And if so how did you do it, thanks

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-09-09**:
Yes I did get it work in fuerte. It's been a little while since you posted so hopefully you got things up and running. However if you're still having some trouble, if you send me a message or post where you're having trouble I'll be more than happy to help you out.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-10**:
@skiesel yes after all i made it work, but thanks.  Right now im working on object detection so if you know anything in the matter, or a good stack in ROS i would really appreciate it.

**Comment by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) on 2013-09-12**:
I think the standard direction to point is OpenCV -- I believe they are external to ROS but provide a wrapper (similar to OMPL)

http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all stacks are maintained anymore or the maintainers are really busy. Releases for new ros versions might then take a while. In that case, I suggest to check out the source code and try to build it on the new ros version. It is likely that a few fixes are required to make the packages work. In that case, you should submit a patch to the corresponding bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4